# Scala.js 1.0.0-RC2 tests failing around jsdom

Tags: scala.js, jsdom

I'm the process of cross-building [UnivEq for Scala.JS 1.0.0-RC2](https://github.com/japgolly/univeq/pull/41). I've got jsdom installed in Travis and tests pass on the 0.6.31 builds, but fail on the 1.0.0-RC2 builds with `TypeError: jsdom.createVirtualConsole is not a function`.

Full error log: https://travis-ci.org/japgolly/univeq/jobs/636731705#L312

How to fix? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because we never ported the additional support of jsdom v12 and later from the Scala.js 0.6.x branch (in [this commit](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/commit/8d1938b6eaa985c933189f0eaf82edee0b3cb897#diff-b097042b8f58e84b044e481289fa803d)) to the newer, separate codebase for `JSDOMNodeJSEnv` at https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-env-jsdom-nodejs. Apparently we forgot about that.

I have created a pull request at https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-env-jsdom-nodejs/pull/33 to fix the issue.

**Edit**: the fix is now published as version 1.0.0-RC3. You can modify your `project/plugins.sbt` to depend on `"org.scala-js" %% "scalajs-env-jsdom-nodejs" % "1.0.0-RC3"` instead of `... % scalaJSVersion`. It is compatible with Scala.js 1.0.0-RC2.

---

**Obsolete old answer**:

You could try using that new version today by checking out the master branch and publishing it locally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-env-jsdom-nodejs.git
$ cd scala-js-env-jsdom-nodejs
$ sbt scalajs-env-jsdom-nodejs/publishLocal
$ cd ..
```

then using version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.0.0-RC2 for `scalajs-env-jsdom` in your `project/plugins.sbt`